# Tricentis Tosca: iterate through elements

Tags: selenium, dom, xpath, find, tosca

Assuming that i am getting 5 elements with the same XPath, is there a way in Tricentis Tosca to iterate those elements? (Some sort of findElementsBy of Selenium). For now all i get is the message: **more than one control found for action**

Comment: can you show an example of your xpath?

Comment: it could be something like this: //a[text()='Click Here']